# Python - List comprehension within File I/O code

Tags: python, list, io

I want to replicate the functionality of the following code using a list comprehension:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    for i in range(1, 6):
        textfile.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

I tried the following:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    textfile.write(str([i for i in range(1, 6)]) + '\n')
```

but it (understandably) prints `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, instead of one number on a single line.

I don't have an answer to 'Why would you want to do that?'; I just want to see if it's possible. Thanks!

**EDIT**: Thank you all for the replies; for some reason I was under the impression that list comprehensions are always encapsulated in `[]`.

Comment: list comprehensions _are_ always surrounded by `[]`. generator expressions are surrounded by `()` and can also be passed directly to functions without doubling the `(())`

Comment: @gnibbler: Heard of generator expressions for the first time today. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing this is [`file.writelines()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines):

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as textfile:
    textfile.writelines(str(i) + "\n" for i in range(1, 6))
```

Comment: Almost -- I don't think that `writelines` actually appends a newline.

Comment: @mgilson Indeed, updated - I was searching for the docs to check.

Comment: writelines was my first impression too -- I don't know why I opted for `join` instead -- Maybe to keep as much of OP's original code as possible.  Anyway, `writelines` is definitely cleaner here.  +1

Answer (score 2):

```
textfile.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1,6)))
```

Is *almost* the same thing.  This will leave off a trailing newline.  If you need that, you could do:

```
textfile.write(''.join('{}\n'.format(i) for i in range(1,6)))
```

Comment: with open('/tmp/foo.txt','w') as f:
    [f.write(str(i)+' ') for i in range(0,10)]

Comment: @Arcturus -- I don't actually recommend this.  List-Comprehensions are for building lists.  If you're not actually going to use the list that it builds, then I think is cleaner to just use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're writing text that will be consumable by some other application, more often than not you're writing CSV, and the `csv` module makes these things easy.

(In this case you only have a single value per line, so this may not be needed.)

```
import csv

with open("file.txt", "wb") as out_f:
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)
    writer.writerows([[i] for i in range(1, 6)])
```

**NOTE**  The `csv` module will take care of converting *int* to *str* for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try,

```
with open('/tmp/foo.txt','w') as f:
    [f.write(str(i)+' ') for i in range(0,10)]
```

with the examples of @monkut or @mgilson

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
open('/tmp/foo.txt','w').writelines(f'{i}\n' for i in range(10))
```